# Django first project import Error

Tags: python, django

**My package:** <kbd>Python 2.7.11+</kbd>
<kbd>Django 1.9.6</kbd>

In my `urls.py` I have imported:

`from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include`

but it's dysplays an error when I type `python manage.py runserver`:

> ImportError: cannot import name patterns

I have tried to change import string with:

`from django.conf.urls.defaults import`

but it causes the following error:

> from django.conf.urls.defaults import

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.7, the urlconf is a simple list and no longer requires the patterns import. So remove patterns from your import, and see the example here on the syntax to use: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: I've removed 'patterns' from import. But now it displays: "TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
"

Answer (score 0):

patterns is deprecated after Django 1.7. You can defines urls simply like this

```js
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('web.urls')),
]
```

or you can import urls from your app and define urls like this

```js
from app import urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include(urls)),
]
```